# Deploy nextjs app to firebase fails but works fine in emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

My next.js app works fine when using the firebase emulator with the below configuration but the same doesn't work when deployed to firebase.

**Error from firebase functions log**

```
Error: Failed to load /500
    at loadComponents (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js:1:1554)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Server.findPageComponents (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:76:257)
    at async Server.renderErrorToHTML (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:138:198)
    at async Server.renderToHTML (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:137:1629)
    at async Server.render (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:74:255)
    at async Object.fn (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:58:672)
    at async Router.execute (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:25:67)
    at async Server.run (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:68:1042)
    at async Server.handleRequest (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:32:504) 


Error: Failed to load /
    at loadComponents (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js:1:1554)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Server.findPageComponents (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:76:257)
    at async Server.renderToHTML (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:137:542)
    at async Server.render (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:74:255)
    at async Object.fn (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:58:672)
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrServer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5008,
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "public": "public"
    }
  }
}
```

**firebase function**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import next from 'next';

const firebaseFunction = functions;

const server = next({
  dev: false,
  dir: __dirname + '/public',
  conf: {
    distDir: '.next',
    experimental: {
      reactRoot: false,
      turboMode: false,
    },
    future: {},
  },
});

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();

exports.ssrServer = firebaseFunction.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  return server.prepare().then(() => nextjsHandle(req, res));
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are indicating that the components have not loaded. Before you deploy to firebase, ensure you run each command respectively

```
npm run dev
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Next 10.2? It could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/24658).